# Active Record Association Product belongs_to User

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to associate a user with their created products but I am having issues with it. My models look like the following.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :category
  belongs_to  :user

  def userid
    @user_id = @product.user
  end  
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :products, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
end
```

I'm getting a `nil object` with the following view `<%= @product.userid %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need the `Product#userid` method at all.
2. In the `Product#userid` method you reference `@product`. That's a `product` instance variable on Product. You don't need an instance variable to refer to an object from itself, you simply use `self`, but it's implicit most of the time. You only actually need it in ambiguous cases (like `user_id = 1` which could either be `self.user_id=(1)` OR assigning a local `user_id` variable to `1`).
3. You don't need to specify the `foreign_key` on your `User` model because you're following convention.

So the following should work for you just fine:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :category
  belongs_to  :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

@product = Product.first
@product.user #=> <User :foo => 'bar'>

@user = User.first
@user.products.create :some_attribute => 'some value'
```

Comment: I'm getting just a hash # when I use    <%= @product = Product.first %>

Comment: Why would you be doing that? You should be fetching data in your controller, not your view. And while the output should look like the hash, it's not actually a hash. Call `@product.class` and you should get back `Product`.

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured everything out. I needed to create a user_id  column in my products table and let Active Record take care of the relationship.